# Loading a website without browser showing spinning wheel

Tags: performance, browser, spinner, loading

I am just curious to know how these websites were made to load only once. If you go to the sites http://fueled.com/ or http://ecap.co.nz/, the browser shows the spinning wheel only the first time the website is loaded. When you navigate to other pages from the navigation menu, like About or Contact or Team, when those pages load, the browser doesn't show the spinning wheel.

How do they make them work like this?

Answer (score 2):

It is because page load is not triggered upon those links. Instead, a post request is triggered and its response will be used. Also, further page loads will be quicker, since scripts, styles and pictures will be cached, that is, saved locally on your computer.

You can check what happens using the browser console's network tab. Click on the last request before you click on such a link. You will see that the request log will not be cleared, but other requests are added. That means there is no page load in the meantime.
[image: This is a screenshot of the network tab of the console]